# At 100% width my divs aren't containing their elements (overlapping?)

Tags: html, css, width, positioning, overlap

Why is it that if I have two container divs set at 100%, one on top of the other, with content inside (imgs and text) they keep overlapping? I want each main container to be its own block.

The container divs are always way above the content it's meant to contain. My two containers aren't floated and their margins are set at 0 and auto. I have divs set as block. The images/text stack appropriately, just not their parent div. I'm also using normalize.css if that's any indicator.

Excuse my code, I'm still learning and messing about so I know it's "dirty." Thanks for any help!

Edit: I went through and deleted the 100%s that Neil mentioned. Still having a problem with the divs not containing their elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="home-hero-image">
            <h1>Gov Defenders Assemble</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="header_container">
        <div class="header_onecol">
            <ol>
                <li class="links">Blog</li>
                <li class="links">Members</li>
                <a href= "/Technology/index.html"><li class="links">Technology</li></a>
                <li class="links">Contact Us</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="intro">
        <p class="maintext">
            We're dedicated to delivering the latest information on current threats, to provide industry best practices, and to enhance every public sector IT professional's understanding of cybersecurity by opening direct conversations between the government and IT community.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="onecol">
        <div class="twocol">
                <h2>The Partners</h2>
                <p>We've come together to offer our views on security technologies and their applications in the government. We want to share our knowledge with you to together fix your cybersecurity problems.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="twocol">
            <div class="twocol">
                <a href="/Partners/DLT Solutions/index.html">
                    <img class="logos" src="images/dltsolutions_logo.jpg">
                </a>
                <a href="/Partners/ForeScout/index.html">
                    <img class="forescout" src="images/forescout_logo.png">
                </a>
                <a href="/Partners/Oracle/index.html">
                    <img class="logos" src="images/oracle_logo.jpg">
                </a>
                <a href="/Partners/SolarWinds/index.html">
                    <img class="logos" src="images/solarwinds_logo.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="twocol">  
                <a href="/Partners/DellSoftware/index.html">
                    <img class="logos" src="images/dell_software_logo.png">
                </a>
                <a href="/Partners/NetApp/index.html">
                    <img class="logos" src="images/netapp_logo.jpg">
                </a>
                <a href="/Partners/RedHat/index.html">
                    <img class=logos src="images/red_hat_logo.jpg">
                </a>
                <a href="/Partners/Symantec/index.html">
                    <img class="logos" src="images/symantec_logo.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="onecol">
        <h2>The Technologies</h2>
        <ol>
            <li class="technologies">
                    <img class="technology" src="images/mobile.png">
                    <h4>Mobile Device Management &amp; Endpoint Security</h4></li>
            <li class="technologies">
                    <img class="technology" src="images/data.png">
                    <h4>Data Loss Prevention</h4></li>
            <li class="technologies">
                    <img class="technology" src="images/monitoring.png">
                    <h4>Continuous Monitoring</h4></li>
            <li class="technologies">
                    <img class="technology" src="images/management.png">
                    <h4>Identity &amp; Access Management</h4></li>
            <li class="technologies">
                    <img class="technology" src="images/cloud.png">
                    <h4>Cloud Security</h4></li>
            </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #888888;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.home-hero-image {
    height: 250px;
    background: url('../images/hero_image.jpg') no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5%;
    font-size: 5em;
}

.header {
    height: 77px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  z-index:999;
}

.header_container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 12px;
}

.header_onecol {
    width: 97%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 1%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('../images/GovDefendersLogo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 24px;
}

ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
}

.links {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.intro {
    background-color: #9d2d31;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.maintext {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 15px auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 2;
}

.twocol {
    width: 47.9%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 1.04%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #db7027;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logos {
    float: left;
    margin: 10% 0 10% 15%;
    width: 150px;
}

.forescout {
    float: left;
    margin: 10% 0 10% 23%;
}

.onecol {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.technologies {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    height: 120px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 5px 2.4% 0;
    background-color: white;
}

h4 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

---

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var win      = $(window),
            fxel     = $(".header"),
            eloffset = fxel.offset().top;

        win.scroll(function() {
            if (eloffset < win.scrollTop()) {
                fxel.addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                 fxel.removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about. When the element is at 'width' property, but when you change it into 'max-width' property, then elements start to overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple instances of margin and padding and I can say with fairly good odds that one of your elements is 100%+margin+padding, hence the overlap.

Comment: So you can't have a class with padding, margin, and 100%? I can't find a one with all three, though I have one with margin at "0 auto" and width at 100%.

What's the rule there and logic? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can but your setting an element to a width of 100% and something with padding/margin is making it jump out. If its not been answered soon I will take another look after dinner :)

Comment: Thanks Neil! Hopefully, I can fix it before then. I'm researching the topic and I will experiment a bit.

Enjoy dinner!

Comment: Think I solved it by removing the 100%s and using overflow: hidden. Thanks!